Removing edges during SIR simulation
To model social distancing during a SIR epidemic, I want to be able to remove or add back edges of the graph during the simulation. I wonder if this is possible using the EoN module, and which simulation method would be most suitable.
I looked at the fast_SIR model, but it does not seem you are able to change the graph during the simulation. The discrete model already seemed more suitable, but nodes recovering after 1 day is not suitable for my project.
